# unrecognized import path (golang google package)

Tags: github, go, google-oauth

**function used:**

```
go get golang.org/x/oauth2/google
```

**expect:**
download package
**what happened?**

```
package cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata: unrecognized import path "cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata" (parsing cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata: XML syntax error on line 9: expected /> in element)
```

thanks for helping

Comment: Try using : 

`go get -u golang.org/x/oauth2/google`

Comment: @Aaqib same result.

Comment: @GholamrezaEghbali `go get golang.org/x/oauth2/google` works for me on right now on go1.9.1 darwin/amd64. What go version are you using?

Comment: @nishanths  go1.8.3 linux/amd64
im going to update and see what will happen.

Comment: @nishanths I update it to last version 1.9.2 and the problem is still remained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue, seems like serving repository from that path is missing,
I find the repository in github and clone it into my $GOPATH/src
then Move the container of project to go.
this is the repository address:

1) `git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go`

2) `mv google-cloud-go $GOPATH/src/cloud.google.com/go/`

Comment: cannot build because of:
../../go/src/golang.org/x/oauth2/google/default.go:16:2: cannot find package "cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata" in any of:
 /usr/local/go/src/cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata (from $GOROOT)
 /home/reza/go/src/cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata (from $GOPATH)

Comment: its funny i have this directory and packages in it!

Comment: ls /home/reza/go/src/cloud.google.com/go/compute/ | grep metadata        
 did you check it ?